# Notifies Thread before it is supposed to be notified, kind of producers consumers problem(White board problem, Can't find the suitable algo)(JAVA)

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, producer-consumer, java-threads

So, I am trying tow write a program where A teacher is given a white board to write lines and the students are supposed to copy it. The teacher is only allowed to write another line on the white board after all the students have completed copying the entered line(Basically teacher can only write one line at a time). Here is the expected output:

[image: Expected Output]

The monitor has been given to White board...

```
class WhiteBoard{
    String text;
    int noOfStudents=0;
    boolean flag=true; //If teacher writes "end" on the white board the program terminates
    int c=0; //if c=0 teacher writes (Counter)
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);

    synchronized public void write(){ //Teacher uses this function
        while (c != 0) {
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
        }
        System.out.print("\nWrite on White Board: ");
        text=sc.nextLine();
        c=1; //To allow the students to copy the line
        if(text.equals("end")){
            flag=false;
        }
        notifyAll();

    }

    synchronized String read(String name){ //Student uses this fucntion
        while (c == 0) {
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
        }

        //I think the error is here:
        c++;
        c=(c%(noOfStudents+1)); //
        
        if(c==0){ //I know this is totally wrong but i cant find a way to put a successful lock
            notify();
        }
        

        return name+" Has finished copying: "+text;
    }

}
```

Output that i get:

[image: Actual Output]

But if i call sleep() in run() method of Teacher and student class the output comes out fine.
Here is the remaining code:

```
class Teacher extends Thread{

    WhiteBoard w;
    Teacher(WhiteBoard w){
        this.w=w;
    }


    public void run(){
        while(w.flag) {
            w.write();
            //If i write sleep here then i get the desired output only
            //try{Thread.sleep(100);}catch(Exception e){}
        }
    }

}

class Student extends Thread{
    WhiteBoard w;
    String name;
    Student(String name,WhiteBoard w){
        this.w=w;
        this.name=name;
        w.noOfStudents++;
    }

    public void run(){
        do{
            //If i write sleep here then i get the desired output only
            //try{Thread.sleep(100);}catch(Exception e){}
            System.out.println(w.read(name));
        }while(w.flag);
    }
}


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // write your code here
        WhiteBoard wh=new WhiteBoard();
        Teacher t=new Teacher(wh);
        Student s1=new Student("Ram",wh);
        Student s2=new Student("Shyam",wh);
        Student s3=new Student("Hari",wh);
        t.start();
        s1.start();
        s2.start();
        s3.start();

    }
}
```

Can you please help me find the algorithm to synchronize the write and read method?

Comment: I'd use a LinkedBlockingQueue as the input of each Student (imo, a queue is one of the best ways to disseminate data/events among threads). This means each Student has its own queue. The Student calls queue.take() until InterruptedException in its run() -> while(true). Whiteboard holds references to all Students and puts a new line into each Student's queue. Do you really need to build the code with Object's monitor and wait()/notifyAll() primitives instead?

Comment: This `c++; c=(c%(noOfStudents+1));` logic is really weird and I don’t even want to think about whether it could work. Why not use something straight-forward like, instead of `c = 1;`, the writer enables the reads with `c = noOfStudents;`, then each reader only needs to do `c--;` and it will reach zero automatically when all readers are done… The other issue is that the `read` method only returns the string, its printing happens *outside* the `synchronized` method, so even if the read and write methods work correctly, the printing may be interleaved.

Comment: @Holger I tried the other way around too.. by decrementing the counter as you said but still it doesnt give the desired output

Comment: As said, the `System.out.println(w.read(name));` statement performs the `println` *outside* the `synchronized` method.

Answer (score 0):

There is a contention between the student threads for access to the white board. The thread scheduler can schedule the same thread to read from the white board successively, not taking turns with the other student threads in the manner you desire. The sleep causes each student thread to pause, letting another student thread to read from the white board. This allows each thread to read from the white board for each message written by the teacher.

Comment: even if notifyAll() wakes random thread ... shouldnt the output still be shown, even though it is repeated?